# how to read value of data-original-title of an HTML element

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to get the value of data-original-title of a `<pre>` element. The HTML looks like this

```
<pre id="pre" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="" data-original-title="18 Jun 2019 06:00:00 AM - 18 Jun 2019 06:30:00 AM"> 
   <input type="radio" name="shifts[]" id="shiftsValue" class="shiftsValue" onclick="shiftCheck();" value="266930360"> 
      sometext 
   <br>
</pre>
```

Since there are many radio buttons, I am able to get the text of the checked radio button by using the code below

```
var input = $('input[type=radio][class=shiftsValue]:checked').closest('pre').text();
```

Now I need to read the info stored in data-original-title. I use bootstrap 3.3.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [jQuery .data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) function.

```
var originalTitle = $('input[type=radio][class=shiftsValue]:checked').closest('pre').data( 'original-title' );
```

Comment: wow .. that is almost way to simple. I tried a dozen way I know but kept thrown off cause in HTML it is data-original-title.
where can I learn more about data() and how data-original-title is accessed from data('original-title')